# Calling an action controller on submit button

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to call a controller action on a form submit button, what is the syntax in twig Please?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is :

```
{# src/Acme/TaskBundle/Resources/views/Default/new.html.twig #}
<form action="{{ path('task_new') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You must set the `action=""` attribute of the form `tag` by using the twig helper `path`. to your correct route.

More information in Symfony2's documentation about [forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html).

Answer (score -3):

In case of Asp.net MVC

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ContorllerName", FormMethod.Post}))
  {
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>

   }
```

This is how you can call a Controller action on submit button

Comment: I apologise, I thought it is for MVC asp.net.